# composer network ping --card admin@decentralized-energy-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

It happened when I executed this command.

```
zcy@ubuntu:~/Decentralized-Energy-Composer/fabric-tools$ composer network ping --card admin@decentralized-energy-network
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.20.3) is not compatible with client (0.19.1)
Command failed
```

I have a problem with my composer runtime version, but I don't know how to fix it

```
 zcy@ubuntu:~$   npm list -g --depth=0
    /home/zcy/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib
    ├── composer-cli@0.19.1
    ├── composer-rest-server@0.19.1
    ├── composer-runtime@0.19.1
    ├── grpc@1.10.1
    └── npm@5.6.0
```

how to solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: hi there, see https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4336 and comment at https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4335#issuecomment-414146159 - sounds like your bna file (which you can recreate using `composer archive create`)  might need upgrading to be compatible.

Comment: When I execute this command，（[cd /Fabirc-tools,./teardownAllDocker.sh]）,the problem was solved.